# Regex correct implementation

Tags: c#, sql, regex

This should be simple, but bear with me here please.  What is it that I'm overlooking?  All I'm trying to do is take in a value that is part of a SQL query and I want to check to make sure it has integers as its value.  If it is, then I allow it to be passed to SQL Server.  I'm getting a notification that my Regex method has invalid arguments.  Thanks in advance for shedding some light on where I'm erring.

```
 string valid2Regex = @"\d{4}"; // regex to check for 4 integers
 Regex rgx = new Regex(valid2Regex);
 string idCheck = id;

 if (rgx.Matches(idCheck, rgx))
        {
            parameters.Add(DataAccess.CreateParameter("@YEAR", SqlDbType.NVarChar, HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Get("Year")));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\d{4}$
```

This constrains it to just 4 digits. Otherwise any 4 digits together within a string would work with yours.

Also, [there is no instance overload which takes those 2 parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), instead use [IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axa83z9t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
if (rgx.IsMatch(idCheck))
{
    ...
```

Comment: Just thought I'd throw it out there that [there isn't in 4.5 either](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx)

Comment: Great point!Adjusted now but this is what I'm getting in VS to go along with the red underline: the best overloaded method for "REGEX" has some invalid arguments.  The example shows Matches(string, int), do I need to adjust something else?

Comment: @Working: your example must not look like your actual code...because your example certainly doesn't use `Matches(string, int)` and nothing but `@"YEAR"` is in all caps.

Comment: Ahh, just refreshed to see the IsMatch...trying now

Comment: @Working use the static method of Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern) instead of creating a new regex object.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\b\d{4}\b`. Maybe the four digits are not put in a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

talking about syntax, you can use Regex in different ways:

```
string match = rgx.Match(idCheck);
```

in the this case you look for expression and expect a single result, es:

```
expr:"\d{4}"   text:"asdfas1234asdfasd"  -> "1234"
expr:"\d{4}"   text:"1234"               -> "1234"
expr:"^\d{4}$" text:"asdfas1234asdfasd"  -> null
expr:"^\d{4}$" text:"1234"               -> "1234"
```

if you want only to check if the string matches you can use:

```
bool found = rgx.IsMatch(idCheck);
```

that works as:

```
expr:"\d{4}"   text:"asdfas1234asdfasd"  -> true
expr:"\d{4}"   text:"1234"               -> true
expr:"^\d{4}$" text:"asdfas1234asdfasd"  -> false
expr:"^\d{4}$" text:"1234"               -> true
```

the method (Matches) in your code is used find multiple instances and returns a MatchCollection:

```
MatchCollection result = rgx.Matches(idCheck, 0);
```

probably the error in your is about the second parameter, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ekkwhs.aspx) is an integer and represents the start position in the string.